# How to get individual fields from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

My JSON looks like this. How do I get a specific field, e.g. "title" or "url"?

```
{
 "status":1,
    "list":
        {
         "204216523":
            {"item_id":"204216523",
             "title":"title1",
             "url":"url1",
            },
        "203886655":
            {"item_id":"203886655",
             "title":"titl2",
             "url":"url2",
            }
        },"since":1344188496,
  "complete":1
 }
```

I know `$result = json_decode($input, true);` should be used to get parsable data in `$result`, but how do I get individual fields out of `$result`? I need to run through all the members (2 in this case) and get a field out of it.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`json_decode()` converts JSON data into an associative array. So to get title & url out of your data,

```
foreach ($result['list'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['title'].','.$value['url'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $result['list']['204216523']['item_id']; // prints 204216523
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` translates your JSON data into an `array`. Treat it as an associative array because that's what it is.